# How to use multiple location classes in xindy?

Tags: indexing, xindy

I'm using `xindy` to typeset an index that I've already created by hand. The `idx` file looks like this:

```
\indexentry{Aboriginal!Advising the Accused}{Ch. 46, S. 3.7.8, P. 208A}
\indexentry{Aboriginal!Definition Of}{Ch. 46, S. 2.1, P. 452B}
\indexentry{Aboriginal Rights!Defence}{Ch. 46, S. 3.1.4(a), P. 109AB}
```

As you can see, the page references follow a pattern of *Chapter-section-page-column*; e.g. *Ch. 46, S. 3.7.7(a), P. 208A*.

My `xdy` file looks like this:

```
(define-alphabet "chapter" ("Ch."))
(define-alphabet "section" ("S."))
(define-alphabet "page" ("P."))
(define-alphabet "column" ("A" "B" "AB" "ABA"))
(define-location-class "combination-locator" :var
  ("chapter" :sep " " "arabic-numbers" 
    :sep ", "
    "section" :sep " "
        "arabic-numbers" :sep "."
        "arabic-numbers" :sep "."
        "arabic-numbers" :sep "("
        "alpha" :sep ")" :sep ", " 
    "page" :sep " " "arabic-numbers" "column"
    ))
```

The problem I've been running into is that the format is slightly variable — sections have at most 4 hierarchical levels, including one that's alphabetical, and `xindy` is having trouble recognizing where one section ends and the other begins:

```
WARNING: location-reference "Ch. 46, S. 2.1, P. 208A" did not match any location-class! (ignored)
```

My sense is that part of the problem is using this complex `location-class`. It seems like it would be easier to create a series of location classes, and then link them together in a meta-location class. However, the documentation doesn't explain how to create a recursive location class.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find anything in the xindy docs that suggests that you can specify optional elements, so it seems like the easiest thing is just to add these location classes to the end of the `xdy` you gave above:

```
(define-location-class "combination-locator-a" :var
  ("chapter" :sep " " "arabic-numbers" 
    :sep ", "
    "section" :sep " "
        "arabic-numbers" :sep "."
        "arabic-numbers" :sep "."
        "arabic-numbers" :sep ", " 
    "page" :sep " " "arabic-numbers" "column"
    ))
(define-location-class "combination-locator-b" :var
  ("chapter" :sep " " "arabic-numbers" 
    :sep ", "
    "section" :sep " "
        "arabic-numbers" :sep "."
        "arabic-numbers" :sep ", " 
    "page" :sep " " "arabic-numbers" "column"
    ))
(define-location-class "combination-locator-c" :var
  ("chapter" :sep " " "arabic-numbers" 
    :sep ", "
    "section" :sep " "
        "arabic-numbers" :sep ", " 
    "page" :sep " " "arabic-numbers" "column"
    ))
```

When I ran your sample `idx` file through that, it produced what looks like appropriate output:

```
  \lettergroup{A}
  \item Aboriginal
    \subitem Advising the Accused, Ch. 46, S. 3.7.8, P. 208A
    \subitem Definition Of, Ch. 46, S. 2.1, P. 452B
  \item Aboriginal Rights
    \subitem Defence, Ch. 46, S. 3.1.4(a), P. 109AB
```